# Adding StatsBase.jl weights methods to a function in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to add methods to a function similar to the example function `my_function` below. These methods should be dispatched when any of the subtypes of [`AbstractWeights`](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/weights/) from the `StatsBase.jl` package are passed.

I don't encounter any problem when writing the example function with Abstract and Primitive types from the `Base` package. E.g.

```
function my_function(v::Array{<:Real,1})
    return sum(v .* 3)/length(v)
end

function my_function(v::Array{<:Real,1}, w::Array{<:Real,1})
    return  sum(v .* w .* 3)/sum(w)
 end

v = [1,2,3]

w = [3,2,1]

my_function(v)
# 6.0
my_function(v, w)
# 5.0
```

However, when adding the methods for the types from `StatsBase.jl` I get `MethodError` errors:

```
using StatsBase

my_function(v::Array{<:Real,1}, w::Array{<:AbstractWeights,1}) = my_function(v,w)

my_function(v::Array{<:Real,1}, w::Array{Weights,1}) = my_function(v,w)

my_function(v, pweights(w))
# ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching my_function(::Vector{Int64}, ::ProbabilityWeights{Int64, Int64, Vector{Int64}})

my_function(v, weights(w))
# ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching my_function(::Vector{Int64}, ::Weights{Int64, Int64, Vector{Int64}})
```

How can I write the methods for the `StatsBase.jl` weights types above?

If the function worked well, the following should be `true`

```
my_function(v, w) == my_function(v, weights(w)) == my_function(v, pweights(w)) == my_function(v, fweights(w))
# true
```

Comment: `sum(v .* w .* 3)/sum(w)` is a very inefficient way to implement the weighted sum. It creates an unnecessary temporary array, and also multiplies every element with 3, instead of just multiplying with 3 at the end. In stead, you can do `3 * dot(v, w) / sum(w)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- `AbstractWeights` is already a vector, so you do not need to wrap it in a vector;
- your implementation is recursive (the method calls itself).

So the way you should implement the code is:

```
my_function(v::Vector{<:Real}, w::AbstractWeights) = sum(v .* w .* 3)/sum(w)
```